# Dynamic Price Change with Paypal API?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, paypal, innerhtml

I have a form asking for amount of widgets they want to purchase, and the end goal would be changing the paypal cost accordingly.
How can I adjust my code to obtain the desired outcome?

```
    var amountOfWidgets = document.getElementById('firstBox').value;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "<input type="hidden" name="amount" value=amountOfWidgets>"
}

</script>
<div id="myCheckout">
</br>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="Example@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="price" name="amount" value="6.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
```

Comment: I know a lot of time since but... have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Give form a name. PayPal usually names it `_xclick`.

Javascript:

```
document._xclick.amount.value = price;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="usd" size="20" name="usd" onchange="workaround()"

function workaround() {
var amount = document.getElementById("usd").value;
   paypal.Button.render({
      rest of paypal code...
      ...
      amount: { total: amount , currency: 'USD' }
      ...
   }
}
```

Will do the trick...